# Generate a random String in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate an array of string from a long predefined array of chars as the following

if I have the following long string:

```
s= 'aardvaqrkaardwolfaajronabackabacusabvaftabalongeabandonabandzonedaba'
```

I want to create a group of random strings based on the following rules

1. the string should be between 4 and 12 chars should be end or start
2. with one of the following chars `{j,q,v,f,x,g,b,d,z}`

Comment: am I right, that you want the characters to be taken from the string `s`? Othewise I do not understand what `s` is for... If so neither `j,q,g or z` are inside that string. Do you still want them to be taken as starting/ending chars?

Comment: and are you allowed to use the same char again? E.g. could the string be `jjjjjjjj` even if there is only 1 j in the string?

Comment: yes the strings should be taken without repeat and sequentially from s

Comment: the s is updated now ...

Comment: I want to split the above long string in substrings that satisfy the mentioned rules

Comment: Ah so they even have to be sequentially unchanged. That changes a lot. Gonna see if I find a working solution for that.

Comment: yes... actually I will tell you what behind that so maybe it will be more clear. if i copy a page from a book and i remove all spaces then i would have a long string came from the combination of the words in that page. then i want to generate some approximate words from that page where these words are not readable but also have the same bigram distribution of the orginal page.

Comment: I claim that bigrams of english is not good way of classifying and detecting the language. however, what i basically look for which can save my help a lot is to generate a random words from text that follow the same bigram distribution but these words are rubbish

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61470/discussion-between-aabualia-and-the-minion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here a solution which gives all strings which fullfill the following rules:

- the starting and ending char has to be from the string:

  `start_end_char= 'jqvfxgbdz';`
- The length has to be between 4 and 8 chars long
- The string has to be sequentially correct. Meaning the resulting
  strings have to appear in the exact same way in the "long" string

So what am I doing?

- First of all I find all the positions where the predefined starting and ending chars appear in the main string (careful I used `s2` instead of `s` as string name).
- Then I get a sorted list of those points (`list_sorted`)
- Next thing is to get for each element a list of indices which acceptable ending chars (following rule 1 and 2 stated above). These are saved in `helper` which has to be a cell-datatype because of different length in the strings
- last but not least I construct all those strings and save them in `resulting_strings` which also have to be a cell-datatype.

  ```
  s2= 'aardvaqrkaardwolfaajronabackabacusabvaftabalongeabandonabandzonedaba';
  start_end_char= 'jqvfxgbdz';
  length_start = length(start_end_char);

  %%finding all positions of possible starting/ending points
  position_char= cell(1,length_start);
  for k=1:length_start
      position_char{k}=find(s2==start_end_char(k));
  end
  list_of_start_end_points=[];
  %% getting an array with all starting/ending points in the given array
  for k=1:length_start
      list_of_start_end_points= horzcat(list_of_start_end_points,position_char{k});
  end
  sorted_list= sort(list_of_start_end_points);
  %% getting possible combinations
  helper = cell(1, length(sorted_list));
  length_helper=[];
  for k=1:length(sorted_list)
      helper{k}=find(and(sorted_list-sorted_list(k)>=4,sorted_list-sorted_list(k)<=8));
      length_helper = length_helper + length(helper);
  end
  resulting_strings = cell(1, length_helper);
  l=1;
  for k=1:length(sorted_list)
      for m=1:length(helper{k})
          resulting_strings{1,l} = s2(sorted_list(k):sorted_list(helper{k}(m)));
          l=l+1;
      end
  end
  ```

This solution is using quite a few loops, while the first 2 loops are negatable (No of loops in the size of acceptable start/ending letters), the later two loops can be quite time consuming if the original string is much longer. So maybe someone will find a vectorized solution for the later loops.

Comment: just realized that my rules differ a bit from yours. In my code the starting AND ending char have to be part of the group `'jqvfxgbdz'` and not just one of them. So you gonna have to rework the later part of the program to fit all cases but those are gonna be a LOOOONG list

Comment: last thing, how i can shuffle these words in the array

Comment: yes i noticed that but this not a major i will sort it out

Comment: A copy from the mathworks site: Well, your array A has n elements, so you use randperm to randomly index your array A.

ix = randperm(n);
Ashuffled = A(ix);